# Where to write the data into the SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, startup

I have understood how to use SharedPreferences. But what I don't understand is where to write the piece of the code to insert data into the shared preferences. This code has to be executed only once during the application launch of the first time.

Further on the first activity can check this SharedPreferences data to know whether the application has been launched for the first time or not.

I hope you understand that I want to WRITE the data into the SharedPreferences for the first and the only time. Where should I be doing that? If written in any activity this code will again be executed on the next activity launch.

Is there an inbuilt variable to find out whether the application was launched for the first time?

Comment: its very simple and you can use many way for this. you have to insert data when app RUN first time so, insert that data first time in DB same time store one boolean var in preferences(true). next time when open app check that variable is true then no need to insert data once again.

Comment: @RajeshRajaram If I write it in onCreate, it would be correct for the first time. However on the following launches of the application this piece of code which inserts data into the SharedPreferences would again be executed overwriting the previous value (that I would have inserted in the previous activity launch).

Comment: @PramodSetlur so using SharedPreferences set a flag 0 and 1. put it in if condition. if first time execute 0th flag second time execute the 1st flag got me?

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is make a sharedPrefs boolean for if the app has been run before. set it to false, and do your intending code if it's false. then when the app finally runs and finishes the code, set the boolean to true.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to do is pretty straighforward.
Put a boolean variable in onCreate of your main activity.
And just set it to false (initial value true), so that you know if it the 1st time your app has run

Comment: This will work if the application is still running. But if the device is restarted then the application will again execute the code present in the onCreate.

I hope that you understood that I want to execute this code of writing into the SharePreferences only ONCE, i.e., right after installation. After that this should not be executed.

Comment: Then maybe you can create a dummy file in the SD card and check if that file exists before writing in the SharedPreferences, or another option would be to create an sql lite db.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [Application](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and write SharedPreferences in onCreate method.

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {    
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun",true);
         if(firstRun){
            //insert your data into the shared preferences here
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
            editor.commit();
        }


        }
}
```

AnroidManifest.xml

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                     android:label="@string/app_name"                     
                     android:name=".MyApplication">
...
</application>
```